# Extracting table from PDFs across multiple PDFs in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to work out the best way to extract a specific table that is always in the same place across a number of PDFs in the most efficient way possible. I've come up with the following code to make it work for one, but having trouble adapting this to do this across all the files with a folder.

```
PDF <- pdf_text("https://www.kmk.org/fileadmin/Dateien/pdf/Statistik/Ukraine/2023/AW_Ukraine_KW_29.pdf") %>%
  readr::read_lines()

PDF.grass <-PDF[c(21:36)] # select lines

all_stat_lines <- PDF.grass[1:17] %>%
  str_squish() %>%
  strsplit(split = " ")# remove empty spaces

all_stat_lines<-all_stat_lines[-c(17)] #remove extra line created

var_lines <- c("State","#_Allg_29KW", "#_Allg_28kw", "#_Ber_29KW", "#_Ber_28kw",  "#_Ins_29KW", "#_Ins_28kw", 
               "Cont_Allg_29KW", "Cont_Allg_28kw", "Cont_Ber_29KW", "Cont_Ber_28kw",  "Cont_Ins_29KW", "Cont_Ins_28kw", "Date") # create variable names
df <- plyr::ldply(all_stat_lines) #create a data frame
colnames(df) <- var_lines
```

I've tried implementing this as a loop after reading all the files in the folder, but had no luck. Basically, if I try lapply to the import it gives me one of two errors

```
#if I run the lapply below with this I get an "Error in normalizePath(pdf, mustWork = TRUE):path[1]="AW_Ukraine_KW_02.pdf": No such file or director"
files <- list.files(path="data/enrolment/Germany/2023" ,pattern = "pdf")


#if I run the lapply below with this I get an "Error in file(con, "rb") : invalid 'description' argument"
files1<- paste0("data/enrolment/Germany/2023/", files)


#this is the lapply for the load
read<-lapply(files, pdf_text(files1) %>%
  readr::read_lines())
```

I've found a way around this using a loop, but I still cant get the rest to work.

```
#to load in all the pdfs
for (i in 1:length(files)){
  print(i)
  pdf_text(paste("data/enrolment/Germany/2023/", files[i],sep = "")) %>% 
    readr::read_lines()-> document_text}

#to select the relevant lines (here no matter with rows I give it, it returns NAs.

select<-lapply(document_text, `[`,c(21:36))

#to turn into df
df<-lapply(select,  function(x) plyr::ldply(x))
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hello!  What does "had no luck" mean?  Did it extract the wrong info, did it give you only one file's worth of info, were there error messages?  What code did you use for your `for` loop attempt?    I would suggest that `lapply()` is the tool for this job - it will output a list and each item in the list will be the result of applying your process to one pdf.

Comment: Hey! Thanks! I've added more details on what isnt working, but it's basically that I don't really know how to approach the selection issue noted above.